# Can't access Joomla control panel

Tags: php, apache, joomla, controls

I've just moved my site from local (xamp on my windows) to AlterVista. 
I developed the site with Joomla. In local all okay. When I upload my site it works but I can no longer access to the Joomla control panel with the default/administrator next URL site.

Comment: What happens? 404 error ... or ?

Comment: How did you upload your site? Did you copied the database content as well? Did you checked the database connection? Does the front end works? And as @Mindgem already asked: please let us know what exactly happens of you try to access your site.

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS   This is the error that it give me... Yes the front end (site) works good. I have checked the database connections,  althought the site don't work. I set the tmp and logs path, i set up the configuration.php file,,,.... Realy i don't know how to do more           If you want you can check at this url:  www.agriturtinglerhof.altervista.org

Comment: Uploaded with filezilla

Comment: It could be related to using the subdomain. You may need to check the .htaccess file also.

Answer (score 0):

Though, more details could help in detecting the problem but please check these if you've not so far:

1. Path to the temp and logs folders in [Joomla! Root]/configuration.php.
2. If you've renamed htaccess.txt, check if .htaccess is all set on the server. Sometimes, your operating system doesn't transfer hidden files and .htaccess can be a hidden file, depending to your OS settings.
3. Call an inner admin page to test if the admin folder is responding. Something like: domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content.
4. Via FTP or Host's file manager check if all files are transferred completely.
5. Clear all of your web browser's cache and retry.

In addition,
I transferred a Joomla! (new version) last week and faced to this. So, it also can be a Joomla! bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Also in the configurazione.php there was a linea, the " public $force_ssl = '0' " that was setted to 1. Also my /administrator/index.php was asking to my a certificate to log in... I had only to set this value to 0 to resolv my "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" problem...
Thanks for time! I Hope this post Will bè helpfull for someone.